# How to show/hide markers that are inside a function using js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I have a map with a lot of markers that are pulled from this function:

```
function showResourcesByName(name) {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.resources.length; i++) {
        var resName = markers.resources[i].name;

        if (resName == name) {
            var resIcon = icons.resources[i].icon;
            var resSize = icons.resources[i].size;
            var resPname = icons.resources[i].pname;

            var customIcon = L.icon({
                iconUrl: resIcon,
                iconSize: resSize, // size of the icon
                iconAnchor:   [resSize[0]/2, resSize[1]/2], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
                popupAnchor:  [2, -resSize[1]/2] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
            });

            for (var j = 0; j < markers.resources[i].coords.length; j++) {
                var x = markers.resources[i].coords[j].x;
                var y = markers.resources[i].coords[j].y;

                L.marker([y, x], {icon: customIcon}).addTo(map).bindPopup(resPname);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I use the code `showResourcesByName("AITokarServer");` to show all markers for that selector (AITokarServer) for example.

I have a sidebar with all categories, and want to show/hide markers if I click on that category. For example, if I click animals, I want to show only the markers from the "animals" group. Also I want to put a show/hide selector on each marker group too, if I click on "Shigi" link I want to show only the Shigi markers, that are pulled from this function: `showResourcesByName("AIShigiServer");`

I trid this example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/LVzmRcsVZ79wZ78E5yBd?p=preview
But I don't know how to work with the function that I use and those selectors to show/hide.

And here is my full code with all the files. Each group is commented in the code where are the function  that pulls the icons.

http://plnkr.co/edit/dVgHt4VK0DnA30M3a8vq?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reach what I want using this:

```
marker = L.marker([y, x], {icon:customIcon}).addTo(map).bindPopup(resPname);

$(marker._icon).addClass('randomClass');
```

This way I can add a class to the markers and better, set the class as a previous variable to match the markers properties.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of doing this would be

1.Drop each category's feature into a [`L.layerGroup`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup)(`L.marker(params).addTo(someLayerGroup)`), and then store that in a JS hash that could be nested to your liking.

```
var myLayerHash = {};
myLayerHash["Animals"] = {};
```

As you loop through each lowest-level category...

```
myLayerHash["Animals"][thisCategory] = someLayerGroup;
someLayerGroup.addTo(map) //if they default to being visible
```

Then you simply work through the hash when directed by user input, and use [map.addLayer(layerGroup) or map.removeLayer(layerGroup) as needed.](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-addlayer), like `map.removeLayer(myLayerHash["Animals"]["Shigi"])`

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't understand the idea using L.layergroup.
I was thinking in something more simple like putting the function that calls all markers by its names inside some kind of div or add a class to it, to hide or show it.
this is the function that calls all markers by the name "AITokarServer":
`showResourcesByName("AITokarServer");`

If you look at the code in plnkr you will see what I am reffering to.